# Sonarqube quality badges on gitlab

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, badge

I have a project on gitlab for which I'm trying to display quality badges from sonarqube on. For that I used the "Get project badges" button on the bottom right corner of your sonarqube project overview. They give you for each badge a Markdown which you can easily copy & paste to your README.md file on gitlab/github.

[image: "Get project badges" window]

Markdown looks like this: `[![Bugs](https://yourprojectonsonarqube/api/project_badges/measure?project=your_project_key&metric=bugs)](https://yourprojectonsonarqube/dashboard?id=your_project_key)`

For me it looks like this on the README.md file(logged in as maintainer):

[image: My view on my repository as logged in Maintainer]

For other users on the project which also have maintainer or developer permissions it looks like this:

[image: The view of other people on my repository logged in also as Maintainer/Developer]

If you click on the missing images, it will redirect you to sonarqube and ask for you to log in. Afterwards the images are visible. How can I change that? I want them to always be visible to every user of my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is for a private project on SonarQube, this is most likely a permissions issue.

There is currently an open issue for SonarQube to allow this to work: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1942

As an FYI, this feature has already been implemented for SonarCloud: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1178.

Comment: thx for your reply. The project on sonarqube is listed as public.

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1942 i dont really see how this is helping. there is no real instructions on how to do it. the moment i click on the provided link i get an "access denied"

Comment: The project on sonarqube is public, but is the sonarqube instance itself public or private? (From the sounds of it in your question it is private as you need to login to access it)

Comment: The link to the JIRA issue is to let you know that SonarQube are looking to implement this feature you require.

Comment: I cannot access / see these issues - have they moved? is this still an issue with sonarqube?