# Sonarqube badges with Gitlab 401

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube

I'm trying to add the sonarqube badge to my Gitlab repository.

I've read some answers that talk about this issue for the private project, but it's not the case for me:
[Sonarqube quality badges on gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693253/sonarqube-quality-badges-on-gitlab)

My project is public:

[image: sonarqube project's permissions]

but still, I get 401 on the badge API endpoint:

```
Request URL: https://{my.sonarqube.domain}/api/project_badges/measure?project={project-key}&metric=alert_status
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401
```

[image: Gitlab project's badges]

Just to clarify more:
The API endpoint is throwing 401 unless I send the auth token with the request.
But I can't set a basic auth on the Gitlab badge section, Can I?

*Sonarqube Version: 8.9 (build 43852)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the same question at SonarCommunity site.:
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/public-project-badge-to-gitlab-401/47766
Thanks for Eng. Sylvain Combe for his answer.

Apparently, This can't be done without authentication, the only option available now is disabling `sonar.forceAuthentication` attribute in your sonar configuration, which will make your sonar accessible by everyone.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround can be achieved waiting for the sonarqube team to solve their authentication problem:

We need to retrieve svg from sonarqube using curl and save them as artifacts

Then we can create custom badge in the gitlab settings.

Ie :

```
badges-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  script:
    - 'curl -u ${sonarqube_token}: "https://example.sonarqube.com/api/project_badges/measure?project=Test&metric=coverage" > sqcoverage.svg'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - sqcoverage.svg
```

Settings in gitlab settings :

Badge image URL

[https://example.gitlab.com/%{project_path}/-/jobs/artifacts/%{default_branch}/raw/sqcoverage.svg?job=badges-job](https://example.gitlab.com/%%7Bproject_path%7D/-/jobs/artifacts/%%7Bdefault_branch%7D/raw/sqcoverage.svg?job=badges-job)